# Задача на python(кортежи)

Tags: python

1. Попросите пользователя ввести произвольную строку.
2. Создайте кортеж, состоящий из символов, введённой пользователем строки.
3. Выведите кортеж, используя цикл for.

Я сделал так и все выводит верно. Вопрос правильно ли я сделал с вашей точки зрения? если нет то как правильней(опять же с вашей точки зрения).

```
stroka=tuple(input('Введите инорфмацию котроую требуться записать в кортеж: '))
print(stroka)
for i in stroka:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Да ну вроде правильно. Но поскольку там расписано по шагам, я бы получение ввода и преобразование в кортеж сделал отдельными строками с промежуточной переменной. И про печать кортежа через `print(stroka)` там вообще-то ничего не написано. И ещё переменные `i`, `j`, `k`, `n` обычно используются для натуральных чисел или индексов . Для печати символов хорошо бы использовать переменную `ch`.

Comment: а как получение ввода и преобразование в кортеж сделать отдельными строками подскажи пожалуйста

Comment: Ну как: `inp = input(...)` и дальше `stroka = tuple(inp)`, вроде это и лишняя переменная, но если в задании описано как отдельный шаг, то может зачем-то и нужно. Но вообще это всё ерунда, не главное